# Dimensioning holes through a hollow shaft

Tags: technical-drawing, drafting

I have three types of holes in a hollow shaft that are perpendicular to the shaft. The first type of hole go only through to the centerline. The second type go all the way through (i.e. out the other side). The third type go all the way through, but are not a mirror image of each other. They are patterned at 160 degrees, instead of 180 degrees. How should I best show these in my drawing?

For "through to centerline" I've seen `THRU` used. (in this first example)

[image]

So how would I show this if it really did go through everything. How would I call this 160 degree pattern out? I tried to show this with several cross sections but it looks terrible.

[image]

Comment: First break the drawing in middle thisway your not showing the uninteresting center gets you a better aspect ratio. Then use in line cross sections this eliminates the need for crosssection marks. Though im not so familiar with ASME style drawings as i only make ISO ones myself.